# Portable Webserver (PHP, MySQL) on CD-ROM

Tags: mysql, xampp, read-only

For a school project, I programmed something based on PHP using a MySQL database. for evaluation, it is necessary to hand the program together with the documentation three times to the teacher -- but the basic question is: How can I append a running program to this?

My first approach was to burn it onto a CD (with a portable version of XAMPP), but will that work? I mean, most actions of the program require access on writing data into the database, which might not be possible because the CD is read-only!

How can I realize this? I don't want to give away three USB sticks either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live-CDs are usually using a ramdisk for the base system or parts of the base system that need to writeable.
I suggest you having a look into a XAMPP live CD (e.g. [lampixx](http://lamppix.tinowagner.com/)) and modify the content of the webdirectory (usually /var/www) of this CD.

Comment: Thx — I didn't think of a __live__-CD, just of a portable XAMPP. Should work, so I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, just a portable XAMPP could cause some difficulties, as everything has to be linked either statically or should match the base system you are going to run it on (which is quite unpredictable).

Comment: btw did you mean `/srv/www'?